# Fill a command on command line as it was typed by user exand

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd like to write a bash script/function that can insert some string on the command line, just like it was typed by a user ?

For example, define a function magic :

```
function magic() {
  echo "ls -a" > 'whatever output that would do the trick'
}
```

Then in bash type :

```
prompt> magic
```

Presse Enter and get result directly injected on command line, ready to be modified or to run with Enter key :

```
prompt> ls -a
```

Simply, this would be something like a function driven alias-expand.

Anyone has an idea on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-answer here. After more search and some tests, I finally achieved to do the trick with this "simple" script :

```
function magic {
if [ "$READLINE_LINE" = "magic" ]
then
    #Do magic
    READLINE_LINE="ls -al"
    READLINE_POINT=6
else
    #exec any other command
    $READLINE_LINE

    #For unknown reason : have to add manually the command in history
    history -s "$READLINE_LINE"

    # Clear buffer for next command
    READLINE_LINE=""
    READLINE_POINT=0
fi
}

# Bind Enter key to magic function
bind -x '"\C-M" : magic'
```

Magic !

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Bash's [programmable completion](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/14/bash-programmable-completion/) feature to support something similar:

```
prompt> magic<tab>
```

I think you could write a tab completion script for `magic` which would replace the command line with something else, even though the typical thing is to add more words without changing the text to the left of the caret.

Comment: Thanks John. This is not exactly the answer of the question asked so i will wait a little more before accepting your answer if anybody has another solution.

Comment: Also i found another way as described in this post : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251155/using-bind-to-read-the-current-command-line

With this bind solution i could write :
`function magic() {
    READLINE_LINE="ls -a"
    READLINE_POINT=5
}

bind -x '"\eW":"magic"'`

But with this, i don't know how to read current buffer in magic function, to change READLINE only if nothing is already typed. Anyone knows ?